# I am trying to compute the average of one column with respect to another columns' ranges

Tags: python

I have a column 'depth' and it is divided into 5 blocks. So depth from 0-500 feet, 500-1,000ft, 1000-1500 ft..etc
I have a corresponding density value in each depth.

I need to find the avergae density at each of the 5 depth blocks

```
| Depth | Density |
|-------|---------|
| 0     | 3.3     |
| 1     | 3.55    |
| 2     | 3.44    |
| ...   | ...     |
| 500   | 3.2     |
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is a pandas dataframe,

```
df.groupby(df['Depth'].floordiv(500)).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

If depth=index, then this code can be simplified some where it divides densities into the blocks.

```
densityblocks = []
# make an empty list for each block
for i in range(num_blocks):
    densityblocks.append([])
# Divide densities into blocks
for k in range(len(depth)):
    if depth[k] < 500:
        densityblocks[0].append(density[k])
    elif depth[k]<1000:
        densityblocks[1].append(density[k])
    # Continue with elif for number of blocks
# calculate average for each block
avg_density = []
for i in range(len(densityblocks)):
    for j in range(len(densityblocks[i])):
        sum = sum + densityblocks[i][j]
    avg_density.append(sum/len(densityblocks[i]))
```

Comment: Thank you. this is a good start but the average values are too high